# Getting song name of streaming track in iTunes with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

How can I get the name of the song of current track in iTunes when this track is a radio?

I mean the string(s) that appears right below the radio name :)

[image]

Quering its name like below gives me the name of the radio (`Trance Channel - DIGGITALLY IMPORTED - we can't define it!`)but not the song

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set thisTrack to current track
    set trackName to the name of thisTrack
    set trackTime to thisTrack's time
end tell
```

which is expected since the info in my library is:
[image]
but is there a way to specially deal this streaming tracks? and get their info correctly like iTunes does in the first picture? I know current track is a radio because its time will be `missing value` and not of the form `MM:SS` if that helps a bit.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I looked in the applescript dictionary for iTunes and searched for "stream"...

```
tell application "iTunes"
    current stream title
end tell
```

Comment: I need to get to understand those dictionaries ... :) 
Thanks is worked like a charm!

Comment: @IvanChau did you find a solution?

Comment: I've been trying to find a way to read the browserWindow view property where the track and artist is displayed.  iTunes application is able to read the stream detail as it's encoded into the stream.  Sadly this is not available on a easy API.  I will share my findings if I am at all possible to find a different route around this.   If anyone has a clue how to read the window directly to the pointed element on the question, that would be great!

Comment: @IvanChau I have managed to find a solution that works with Beats 1 and makes reasonable sense. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917619/580513

Answer (score 3):

It appears that, in iTunes 12.2, a whole variety of interesting things are going on.

1. `current stream title` returns `missing value` when requesting the name of a stream coming from "For You" (e.g. something *not* in your current music library). `name of the current track` doesn't exist. For example, I'm listening to "Alternative Gems: 1994" from "For You" right now (Yay- grad school days) and I can't get any information about what is playing. If I go to the album the track is playing from to play something else, `missing value` and error -1728 on `name of current track` too.
2. When listening to Beats 1 radio as per @ivan above, I also get `missing value` *but* for `name of the current track` I get "Beats 1". As @dougscripts points out, the `stream title` stuff varies all over the map.
3. Listening to a *radio* station created via a "For You" seems to give me the correct `name of the current track`.

So, in short, chaos.

Comment: Did you get a resolution for Beats 1?

Comment: I managed to find the solution to handling Beats 1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917619/580513

Comment: Weird behaviour with a Classic FM (UK commercial radio station) stream too - where iTunes occasionally shows things like 'ADBREAK_1234567890....' but *stream title as text* is 'missing value' at that moment.   Also, I've sometimes found the metadata displayed on screen is sometimes missing when iTunes is full screen but present when viewing the mini player.

Answer (score 1):

Not all streamers will format the stream data the same, so results from the current stream title property may not be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Much more hacking and I finally have found a way to get the data directly out from iTunes using the SDK.

This method will check the `currentTrack` like normal, but when it's detected that the `artist` is missing (a common understanding when the track is being streamed), we fall down to getting the values from the LCD display using values provided by Accessibility.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript
/* globals Application */
function main () {
  var itunes = new Application('iTunes')
  var currentTrack = itunes.currentTrack
  var output = {
    name: currentTrack.name(),
    artist: currentTrack.artist(),
    position: itunes.playerPosition()
  }
  if (currentTrack.artist() === '') {
    var app = new Application('System Events')
    var itunesProcess = app.applicationProcesses.byName('iTunes')
    // Get the text values from the first scrollable area which is the LCD Display
    var arr = itunesProcess.windows[0].scrollAreas[0].staticTexts

    output.name = arr[0].name()
    // Clean up the artist name, as it may contain the Show Name. 
    output.artist = arr[2].name().replace(' — ' + currentTrack.name(), '')
  }
  return JSON.stringify(output, null, 2)
}
main()
```

Example output:

```json
{
    "name": "Wild Smooth (Gundam Radar Rip)",
    "position": "34:06",
    "artist": "MUBLA"
}
```

Be sure to `chmod +x` this script.

Note, it requires the calling application to be added to [Accessibility Privacy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/291614/91737)

Answer (score 1):

Another option - given the inconsistency of the output - might be to playback in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org) and query that instead - AppleScript support is pretty limited but at least [the source code](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/1c2f90725a016ee19523f63c23fb68e5791ce35e/modules/gui/macosx/os-integration/applescript.h) is available so you know what you can query.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "VLC" to get name of current item'
```

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of tearing my hair out trying to figure this out myself. 
I have managed to find a very hacky solution to this exact issue.

*your not going to like it though, be warned*.

In order to get the current playing track even if the audio is being streamed from Beats radio, you're going to have to consider a OCR approach (taking a screencapture, converting the image to text)

The following Ruby code will get you up-and-running with this solution.

It will check the current track, and if the `artist` field is blank, (which is the case when a track is streamed) then it fall's to the OCR method.

```ruby
require 'json'
require 'rtesseract'
class CurrentTrack
  def self.check
    js_command = %Q{var itunes = Application("iTunes");
    var currentTrack = itunes.currentTrack;
    JSON.stringify({
      window_bounds: itunes.windows[0].bounds(),
      name: currentTrack.name(),
      artist: currentTrack.artist(),
      position: itunes.playerPosition()
    })
    }
    command = "osascript -l JavaScript -e '#{js_command}'"
    result =  `#{command}`
    json = JSON.parse(result, symbolize_names: true)
    json[:position] = json[:position].to_i
    json[:cue] = Time.at(json[:position]).utc.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if json[:artist] == ''
      sc_command = %Q{screencapture -R #{json[:window_bounds][:x]},#{json[:window_bounds][:y].to_i + 30},#{json[:window_bounds][:width]},#{json[:window_bounds][:height]} capture.png}
      `#{sc_command}`
      image = RTesseract.new("capture.png", processor: 'none')
      ocr = image.to_s.split("\n") # Getting the value
      unless ocr.first == 'Soulection'
        json[:name] = ocr.first
        json[:artist] = ocr[1].split(' — ').first
      end
    end
    json.delete :window_bounds

    json
  end
end
```

You'll need to install [rtesseract](https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract) to get this working.

Caveats,  this script requires the iTunes mini-player window to be visible somewhere on your desktop.